# Spring Boot Unit testing with request scope bean dependency

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-test

I'm trying to run Unit tests on a service class that has an auto wired dependency which is **request scoped**. When running the unit test, it seems like spring container is unable to find the bean to auto wire into the service class. What should I do to fix this?

**Application.java**

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

}
```

**AppConfig.java**

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfig {

    @Bean
    @Scope("request")
    public ClassA classA(){
        return new ClassA();
    }
}
```

**ServiceA.java**

```
@Service
public class ServiceA {

    @Autowired
    private ClassA classA;

    public void doSomething(){
        String value = classA.getValue();
        System.out.println(value);
    }
}
```

ServiceTest.java

```
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
class ServiceATest {

    @Test
    void contextLoads() {
    }

}
```

**Error message**

> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
> Error creating bean with name 'serviceA': Unsatisfied dependency
> expressed through field 'classA'; nested exception is
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ScopeNotActiveException:
> Error creating bean with name 'classA': Scope 'request' is not active
> for the current thread; consider defining a scoped proxy for this bean
> if you intend to refer to it from a singleton; nested exception is
> java.lang.IllegalStateException: No thread-bound request found: Are
> you referring to request attributes outside of an actual web request,
> or processing a request outside of the originally receiving thread? If
> you are actually operating within a web request and still receive this
> message, your code is probably running outside of DispatcherServlet:
> In this case, use RequestContextListener or RequestContextFilter to
> expose the current request.